# Visualize Hierarchical Data

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, data-visualization

I have a data visualization application in node and backbone.  My data is in a hierarchical form, so I have done my R&D but couldn't find a useful tool.  What are the best tool libraries that I can easily integrate into my application, to usefully visualize hierarchical data?

I have checked these links:

```
http://gephi.org/features/
http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/COM/Treemap
http://thewhyaxis.info/bubble-tree/
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be choosing [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) or [rapheal.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) for this task.

There are a lot of examples on the web from which you may be able to to tweak your stuff.

#### Examples of visualizations built on D3:

1. http://biovisualize.github.io/d3visualization/
2. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/example/
3. http://christopheviau.com/d3list/

#### Note:

If you would like to compare D3 and raphealjs check:
[D3.js vs Raphael.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219732/d3-js-vs-raphael-js)

D3 rocks in terms of the amount of documentation, tutorials, and the demos that are out there on the web. IMHO you should go with D3, if support for earlier versions of IE is not a concern for you.

Answer (score 3):

In your scenario what i think [D3 JS](http://d3js.org/) is the best tool yet . I think it will fulfill your needs . cheers :-)